# insert data to database give error result after re edit

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i found the insert to database code on internet, use it for trying and its works. but, after i add on some more column, i got error on inserting data to database. which i'm using this code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
```

to determine error location, but its show no error on coding. only goes to error result. could anyone help me looking for my mistake and my code error?

here is my insert2_db.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['password']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXA_mySQL</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">function checkinput() { 
    var id_mesin = document.getElementById('id_mesin').value;  
    if(!id_mesin.match(/\S/)) {
        alert ('Please enter Machine ID');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form_insert" method="post" action="insert_ac.php" onSubmit="return checkinput(this)">
<table width="100%" height="398" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="9"><strong>Insert Data Into EXA_mySQL Database </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="106">MACHINE ID</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="id_mesin" type="text" id="id_mesin"></td>
<td colspan="2">BRAND</td>
<td width="9">:</td>
<td width="164"><select name="jenama">
  <option selected>Please select :</option>
  <option value="SHARP">SHARP</option>
  <option value="TOSHIBA">TOSHIBA</option>
  <option value="CANON">CANON</option>
  <option value="SAMSUNG">SAMSUNG</option>
  <option value="MEXTEC">MEXTEC</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MODEL</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3"><input name="model" type="text" id="model"></td>
<td colspan="2">METER START</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="meter_awal" type="text" id="meter_awal" value="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SERIAL NO</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3">MACHINE</td>
<td colspan="2">FEEDER</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>FINISHER</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_mesin" type="text" id="siri_mesin"></td>
  <td colspan="3"><input name="siri_feeder" type="text" id="siri_feeder"></td>
  <td><input name="siri_finisher" type="text" id="siri_finisher"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STOCK IN</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="58">DATE</td>
<td width="8">:</td>
<td width="220"><input type="text" name="stok_in" id="stok_in"></td>
<td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="in_do" id="in_do"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LOCATION</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="3"><select name="lokasi">
  <option selected>Please select :</option>
  <option value="HQ WAREHOUSE">HQ WAREHOUSE</option>
  <option value="CHENDERING WAREHOUSE">CHENDERING WAREHOUSE</option>
</select></td>
<td colspan="2">J.S.O</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="js_order" id="js_order"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STOCK OUT</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>DATE</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="stok_out" id="stok_out"></td>
<td colspan="2">D.O NO </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="out_do" id="out_do"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CUSTOMER</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="7"><input name="pelangan" type="text" id="pelangan" size="90"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ADDRESS</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="7"><textarea name="pelangan_alamat" cols="69" id="pelangan_alamat"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>CONTACT PERSON</td>
<td>:</td>
<td colspan="4"><input name="pelangan_person" type="text" id="pelangan_person" size="50"></td>
<td width="109">NO TEL/HP</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pelangan_no" id="pelangan_no"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>TECHNICIAN INCHARGE</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="4"><input name="tech" type="text" id="tech" size="50"></td>
  <td>NO TEL/HP</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tech_no" id="tech_no"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>STATUS</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td colspan="3"><select name="status">
    <option selected>Please select :</option>
    <option value="ORDER PURCHASE">ORDER PURCHASE</option>
    <option value="RENTAL">RENTAL</option>
    <option value="HIRE PURCHASE">HIRE PURCHASE</option>
  </select></td>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><input type="reset" value="Clean" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and my insert_ac.php

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || (trim($_SESSION['password']) == '')) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXA_mySQL</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function CloseWindow() {
    window.close(); 
    window.opener.location.reload();
}

//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","exa");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$id_mesin=$_POST['id_mesin'];
$jenama=$_POST['jenama'];
$model=$_POST['model'];
$siri_mesin=$_POST['siri_mesin'];
$siri_feeder=$_POST['siri_feeder'];
$siri_finisher=$_POST['siri_finisher'];
$meter_awal=$_POST['meter_awal'];
$lokasi=$_POST['lokasi'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$pelangan=$_POST['pelangan'];
//$rekod=$_POST['rekod'];
$stok_in=$_POST['stok_in'];
$stok_out=$_POST['stok_out'];
$in_do=$_POST['in_do'];
$out_do=$_POST['out_do'];
$pelangan_alamat=$_POST['pelangan_alamat'];
$pelangan_no=$_POST['pelangan_no'];
$pelangan_person=$_POST['pelangan_person'];
$js_order=$_POST['js_order'];
$tech=$_POST['tech'];
$tech_no=$_POST['tech_no'];

//$sql2="SELECT * FROM aset where id_mesin = '".$id_mesin."'";
//$result2=mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
$sql="INSERT INTO aset(id_mesin, jenama, model, siri_mesin, siri_feeder, siri_finisher, meter_awal, lokasi, status, pelangan, stok_in, stok_out, in_do, out_do, pelangan_alamat, pelangan_no, pelangan_person, js_order, tech, tech_no) VALUES('$id_mesin', '$jenama', '$model', '$siri_mesin',  $siri_feeder, $siri_finisher, '$meter_awal', '$lokasi', '$status', '$pelangan', '$stok_in', '$stok_out', '$in_do',  $out_do, $pelangan_alamat, '$pelangan_no', '$pelangan_person', '$js_order', '$tech', '$tech_no')";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if($result){//if ($result2 !== 1){

echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<th><form>";
echo "<input type='button' onClick='CloseWindow()' value='Back to Exa_mySQL'>";
echo "</form></th>}";

}//}    
else {
echo "Data error, please check your submit.";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to insert form</a>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>


</body>
</html>
```

i'm also using some dropdown list as input on my form, which initial value = Please select: and it has null value. i cant insert data even i put all information on my insert form, all goes to this error result.

```
echo "Data error, please check your submit.";
```

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say the error is?

Comment: You're using mysqli, so why aren't you using parametrized queries? You're also not escaping the data, so you're subject to SQL injection.

Comment: what is you print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: `mysqli_error()` dont say any error. but the result only goes to "Data error, please check your submit." and i'm trying to running this in offline ( LAN only ). i think it safe from SQL injection.

Comment: @CodingAnt, are this `print_r($_POST)` to view `$_POST` error? and where should i put it on my page to check the error?

Comment: @newbie just for verifying your post data , it will be helpful for debugging

Comment: its show `Array ( [id_mesin] => HT1-001 [jenama] => Please select : [model] => [meter_awal] => 0 [siri_mesin] => [siri_feeder] => [siri_finisher] => [stok_in] => [in_do] => [lokasi] => Please select : [js_order] => [stok_out] => [out_do] => [pelangan] => [pelangan_alamat] => [pelangan_person] => [pelangan_no] => [tech] => [tech_no] => [status] => Please select : [Submit] => Submit ) Data error, please check your submit.
Back to insert form`. what does this error means?

Comment: @CodingAnt, me already change my array list to be same as from `print_r($_POST)` but still goes to error result.

Comment: @CodingAnt, its done. i found the error. thanks for your help. mysqli statement got some declaration mission quote ''.

Comment: @newbie awesome ! good work , keep up

Comment: yeah. me use around 3 hour to review my code and find the error. thanks so much to you. next i'm learning about prevent duplicate data insert to DB. i'll post question again if i got any error. :)